# c++0x regex works with clang but not with gcc 4.9.2

Tags: regex, c++11, gcc4.9

I am parsing a multiline text records that look like below:

```
> UniRef50_A0A091LJV8 Lysozyme g (Fragment) n=2 Tax=Chlamydotis 
macqueenii RepID=A0A091LJV8_9GRUI
Length=186

 Score =   114 bits (285),  Expect = 3e-30, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
 Identities = 54/83 (65%), Positives = 65/83 (78%), Gaps = 0/83 (0%)

Query  1   ASCKTAKPEGLSYCGVSASKKIAERDLQAMDRYKTIIKKVGEKLCVEPAVIAGIISRESH  60
       AS  TA+PEGLSY GVSAS+KIAE+DL+ M +++  I +V     V+PA+IAGIISRESH
Sbjct  17  ASEATARPEGLSYAGVSASEKIAEKDLKNMQKHQDKITRVANSKGVDPALIAGIISRESH  76

Query  61  AGKVLKNGWGDRGNGFGLMQVDK  83
            G VL+NGWGD  N FGLMQVDK
Sbjct  77  GGTVLENGWGDHNNAFGLMQVDK  99
```

I use a few regular expressions to extract data from such records. All they  work when compiled with clang (MacOS X) and gcc 4.9.2 (Ubuntu). One of them however throws a `regex_error` when compiled with gcc. Here is the Minimal (non)-Working Example:

```
#include <regex>

const std::string regex_string_OK_1 = "\\[(.+?)\\]";
const std::string regex_string_OK_2 = "Tax\\s*?=\\s*?([\\n\\w ]*?)\\s*?RepID";
const std::string regex_string_PROBLEM = "Query\\s+?(\\d+?)\\s+?([_\\-[:alnum:]]+?)\\s+?(\\d+?)\\n.+?\\nSbjct\\s+?(\\d+?)\\s+?([_\\-[:alnum:]]+?)\\s+?(\\d+?)\\n";

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

std::regex regex_OK_1(regex_string_OK_1);
std::regex regex_OK_2(regex_string_OK_2);

std::regex regex_PROBLEM(regex_string_PROBLEM); // This line throws regex_error on Ubuntu

  return 0;
}
```

I tested all the regex string with https://myregextester.com, they work just fine. Also, the code compiled on MacOS with clang parses lots of real case data with no problems. But now I have to run the code on Linux/gcc system.

Comment: From what I have seen on SO, even gcc 4.9 is still buggy with regex. Perhaps, you need to get a yet newer version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to completely reedit this answer, as I tested on http://melpon.org/wandbox/ your code under clang and gcc in various versions, I am starting to think that gcc does not recognize `\-` as a valid escape for hyphen (actually in all versions).

Your example seems correct to me now: `[_\\-[:alnum:]]` already contains escape for hyphen : `\\-` but for some reasons gcc does not like it. So I suggest following character class:

```
 `[-_[:alnum:]]`
```

if you need to match also slash : `\` then you should add `\\\\` (I assumed previously that was Your intention).

ps. my previous answer left `\\` which on the other hand caused exceptions on clang, but that was incorrect regexp as it ended in escaping bracket: `\[` which was nonsense - but why not on gcc?

Comment: I accepted that answer because that fixed problems with gcc. But now the code  throws an exception on MacOS (clang)...

Comment: @tnorgd see my edit. also you can quicly test your code under various versions of gcc/clang here: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lg9fG7E5Yu2KqMeK